# Create Bookmark in PDF statement created by Jasper and iText

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, itext

I am using **JasperReports** and **iText** to create a PDF document. I have a jrxml template for dynamic PDF content and it is getting converted into a .jasper file.

I am filling the .jasper file with content and exporting to PdfContentByte which gets added as a page with iText code. The iText code appends 1 static PDF page already present in server and generates final document.

I want to import bookmarks defined/created in jrxml (or which are in in the .jasper) and add them using iText classes such as PdfOutline to create bookmarks when generating the final document.

How can this be done?

Comment: Show us some code, because when you say "exporting to `PdfContentByte`" that sounds like you're doing it wrong. Exporting to `PdfContentByte` throws away bookmarks if there are already bookmarks in place. Are there already bookmarks available *before* you export to `PdfContentByte`?

Comment: JasperReports can already add bookmarks to the PDF it generates, and if you append the additional page with iText in the appropriate way, those bookmarks will remain.